# Selecting the components of a vector inside an if statement inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, compiler-errors

I'm trying to check if the absolute value of each component of the vector *differenza* inside a for loop is greater than 0.001 by using if statements, but it seems that I'm not selecting a component because I got the error:

```
Warning in if (abs(differenza[i]) > 0.001) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Which kind of mistake did I make?

```
lambda = 10
n = 10
p = lambda/n
K = 10
x = 0:K

denbinom = dbinom(x, n, p)
denpois = dpois(x, lambda)

differenza = denbinom - denpois

for (i in differenza) {
  if (abs(differenza[i]) > 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i > 0.001, "\n")
  }
  if (abs(differenza[i]) <= 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i, "ok")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use `seq_along()`:

```
for (i in seq_along(differenza)) {
  if (abs(differenza[i]) > 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i > 0.001, "\n")
  }
  if (abs(differenza[i]) <= 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i, "ok")
  }
}
```

You can also simplify your if statement:

```
for (i in seq_along(differenza)) {
  if (abs(differenza[i]) > 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", TRUE, "\n")
  }else {
    cat("Componente", i, "ok", "\n")
  }
}
```

#### Edit

If you wish to print the real values of `i`:

```
for (i in seq_along(differenza)) {
  if (abs(differenza[i]) > 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i,  "> 0.001", "\n")
  }
  if (abs(differenza[i]) <= 0.001) {
    cat("Componente", i, "ok", "\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Mwavu thank you for your answer...I tryed the code and the output is strange: Componente 1 okComponente 2 okComponente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE 
Componente TRUE

Comment: Fundamentally it's what your for loop does. You could tell me what you want it to do then I can help you.

Comment: I'd like to print the message "component i>0.001" when abs(differenza[i]) is > 0.001, and I'd like to print "ok" when abs(differenza[i]) is <= 0.001. The first code prints TRUE, but there isn't any TRUE text in my code.

Comment: Check my edit. Hopefully that's what you want.